# HTML form: output # as part of URL

Tags: html, forms, fragment-identifier

If `YZ56765ZX` is entered into the input field, the form should generate the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/quick-access/?track-code#trackingIds=YZ56765ZX
```

The form:

```html
<form enctype="text/plain" action="http://www.example.com/quick-access/">
    <input type="text" name="track-code#trackingIds" id="keys" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that I am unable to generate a URL that includes the: `#` character. The `#` will become `%23` instead.

Comment: What are you using to generate the URL?  What programming language?  Do you have a program that you have now that is generating HTML that is not doing what you want?

Comment: Do you have control at the receiving end? The url encoding can be reversed by the receiver to get the %23 converted back to #.

Comment: `website.com` is external website not under my control. This html form for check tracking code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use these kind of reserved symbols. Consider reading ["Reserved Characters" (RFC 3986)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

You can still try something like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamnikhilnk/3Lg5bwLg/).

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function() {
    this.action += '?track-code#trackingIds=' + this.keys.value;
}
```

```html
<form enctype="text/plain" action="http://www.example.com/quick-access/">
    <input type="text" id="keys" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```